# Переменная использует неправильную функцию при парсинге на Python BS4

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Я пытаюсь спарсить html страницу при помощи python, используя библиотеку BS4.

Я написал небольшой код для получения `data-id` из небольшого кусочка html, так как эта проблема с find у меня возникает в любом участке кода:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


async def parse():
    my_html = '<li rel="" class="wrap tleft rel fleft ad_idRJQvg " data-adnumber="1" data-id="794072456"></li>'

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        markup = my_html,
        features = "lxml"
    )

    x = soup.find("li", class_ = "wrap").attrs["data-id"]
    print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(parse())
```

После запуска этого кода у меня отображается ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\my business\application\app\manage.py", line 49, in <module>
    run(parse())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\Projects\my business\application\app\manage.py", line 44, in parse
    x = soup.find("ul", class_ = "wrap").attrs["href"]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

Я точно знаю что написал всё правильно так как не второй день этим занимаюсь..
Я просмотрел то как VS Code определяет функцию find и какие аргументы принимает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте видно, что всёв порядке, так как после выполнения функции `find` должна быть доступна функция attrs, которая должна достать `data-id` из моего кусочка html, но этого по какой-то причине не происходит и как я уже понял `find` определяется как обычная python функция, которая доступна из коробки для поиска подстроки в тексте.

Я использую python версии 3.10.5 а также pip версии 23.1.2

1. Подскажите как я могу решить данную проблему?
2. Какие есть способы её решения? Так как я просто отправил кусочек для понимая, но html страница по объёму довольно большая.

Comment: дайте ссылку на страницу (или проверьте сами). Похоже, что страница - `js` генерируемая, а это значит, что одним `BS` тут не обойтись, потому что он (`BS`), увы, не может в `javascript`

Comment: @n1tr0xs Вы неправильно подумали, я прикрепил выше небольшую часть html кода с которого хотел получить data-id. Как вы могли ранее увидеть у меня нет в коде никаких get запросов на получение html от сайта, я прикрепил готовый html код, который должен был без проблемно сработать с моим кусочком html. Но python определяет функцию find как из коробки, а не как функцию для тега от BS4.

Comment: [код работает](https://onlinegdb.com/OCwNEi4xB)

Comment: да и питон на вашем скриншоте верно определяет функцию как из модуля `bs4`... *look in the children of this PageElement...*

Comment: @n1tr0xs спасибо за подтверждение, я знал что это должно было прекрасно работать, но у меня не работает.

Comment: @n1tr0xs и да на скриншоте определяет также правильно, но не работает корректно, так как иначе зачем бы я задавал данный вопрос.

Comment: Сначала хотел написать ответ, но потом подумал что хватит и комментария, в приведенном Вами коде Вы пишете `li` но в скриншоте и в ошибке `ul` только исправив `li` на `ul` мне удалось воспроизвести Вашу ошибку.

Comment: И в любом случае лучше делать проверку на `None` прежде чем что-то извлекать из данных.